# How to get table column-name/header for SQL query in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook, database-cursor

I have the data in pandas dataframe which I am storing in SQLITE database using Python. When I am trying to query the tables inside it, I am able to get the results but without the column names. Can someone please guide me.

```
sql_query = """Select date(report_date), insertion_order_id, sum(impressions), sum(clicks), (sum(clicks)+0.0)/sum(impressions)*100 as CTR
            from RawDailySummaries
            Group By report_date, insertion_order_id
            Having report_date like '2014-08-12%' """

cursor.execute(sql_query)
query1 = cursor.fetchall()

for i in query1:
    print i
```

Below is the output that I get

```
(u'2014-08-12', 10187, 2024, 8, 0.3952569169960474)
(u'2014-08-12', 12419, 15054, 176, 1.1691244851866613)
```

What do I need to do to display the results in a tabular form with column names

Answer (score 17):

In DB-API 2.0 compliant clients, `cursor.description` is a sequence of 7-item sequences of the form `(<name>, <type_code>, <display_size>, <internal_size>, <precision>, <scale>, <null_ok>)`, one for each column, as described [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes). Note `description` will be `None` if the result of the execute statement is empty.

If you want to create a list of the column names, you can use list comprehension like this: `column_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]` then do with them whatever you'd like.

Alternatively, you can set the `row_factory` parameter of the connection object to something that provides column names with the results. An example of a dictionary-based row factory for SQLite is found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory), and you can see a discussion of the `sqlite3.Row` type below that.

Comment: brilliant! Just an example in case someone is trying to load an sql query into a pandas dataframe respecting column names from query: 
```cur.execute(q)

import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_records(cur, columns=[i[0] for i in cur.description])
```

Comment: Save my day! Tks!

Answer (score 8):

Step 1: Select your engine like pyodbc, SQLAlchemy etc.

Step 2: Establish connection
`cursor = connection.cursor()`

Step 3: Execute SQL statement
`cursor.execute("Select * from db.table where condition=1")`

Step 4: Extract Header from connection variable description

```
headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
print(headers)
```

Comment: and to print out the content of rows use :  for row in cursor: print(row)

Answer (score 5):

Try Pandas .read_sql(), I can't check it right now but it should be something like:

```
 pd.read_sql( Q , connection)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a sample code using `cx_Oracle`, that should do what is expected:

```
import cx_Oracle


def test_oracle():
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'password', 'tns')
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT day_no,area_code ,start_date from dic.b_td_m_area where rownum<10')

        #only print head
        title = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]
        print(title)

        # column info
        for x in cursor.description:
            print(x)

    finally:
        cursor.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_oracle();
```