# SAP HANA hdblci package - get data with column names

Tags: python-3.x, hana

I'm using the `hdbcli` package to load data from SAP HANA.

**Problem:** When loading data, I only get the value rows without the actual headers of the SQL table.

When I load only 3 columns (as below), I can manually add them myself, even though it is very ugly. This becomes impossible when I execute a `Select *` statement, as I really don't want to have to add them manually and might not know when there is a change.

**Question:** Is there a flag / command to get the column headers from a table?

Code-MRE:

```
#Initialize your connection
conn = dbapi.connect(
    address='00.0.000.00',
    port='39015',
    user='User',
    password='Password',
    encrypt=True, 
    sslValidateCertificate=False
)

cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_command = "select TITLE, FIRSTNAME, NAME from HOTEL.CUSTOMER;"
cursor.execute(sql_command)
rows = cursor.fetchall()  # returns only data, not the column values
for row in rows:
    for col in row:
        print ("%s" % col, end=" ")
    print (" ")
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get table column-name/header for SQL query in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34214031/how-to-get-table-column-name-header-for-sql-query-in-python). It may look like not applicable, but the description is very clear and precise with reference to basics: DB API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @astentx' comment I found a solution:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql_command = "select TITLE, FIRSTNAME, NAME from HOTEL.CUSTOMER;"
cursor.execute(sql_command)
rows = cursor.fetchall()  # returns only data, not the column headers
column_headers = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]  # get column headers
cursor.close()
conn.close()

result = [[column_headers]]  # insert header
for row in rows:  # insert rows
    current_row = []
    for cell in row: 
        current_row.append(cell)
    result.append(current_row)
```